# Filtering labels to show user from Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, filtering, responsive

I'm working on a Chart.js project, On it, I will have a bunch of data. If the user wants to see a specific date ex:(10/10/2019), I would like to get all the data from that specific date, show him, and when he clears the input it will turn back to its normal state. At the moment I don't have any idea how to do it, I looked into searching for chart labels, but I didn't have success.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiJey.png) is an image of my chart.

This is my button method:

```
 <div class="chart1">
      <canvas id="mychart1" ></canvas>
      <form method="post">
        <p class="datafilter">Filtrar data:<input type="date" id="datafilter">
        <button type="submit" id="subfilt">FILTRAR</button></p>
      </form>
 </div>
```

This is my chart.js:

```
<script>
    chartIt();

    async function chartIt(){
      var lbl = [<?php echo $labels; ?>];
      var ctx1 = document.getElementById('mychart1');

      var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx1, {
          type: 'line', 
          data: {
            labels: lbl,
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "Corrente 1",
                data: [<?php echo $datacor1;?>],
                borderWidht: 6,
                borderColor: 'red',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent'
              },
              {
                label: "Corrente 2",
                data: [<?php echo $datacor2; ?>],
                borderWidht: 6,
                borderColor: 'blue',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent'
              },
              {
                label: "Corrente 3",
                data: [<?php echo $datacor3; ?>],
                borderWidht: 6,
                borderColor: 'green',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent'
              },
              {
                label: "Corrente Total",
                data: [<?php echo $datatotcor; ?>],
                borderWidht: 6,
                borderColor: 'black',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent'
              },
            ]            
          },
          plugins: [

          ],
          options: {
            scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true
                }
              }],
              xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                  display: false
                }
              }]
            },

            title: {
              display: true,
              fontSize: 20,
              text: "Gráfico das Correntes"
            },

            labels: {
              fontStyle: "bold",
            },

            layout: {
              padding: {
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: 0,
                bottom: 0
              }
            },
            tooltips: {
              enabled: true,
              mode: 'single',
              responsive: true,
              backgroundColor: 'black',
              titleFontFamily: "'Arial'",
              titleFontSize: 14,
              titleFontStyle: 'bold',
              titleAlign: 'center',
              titleSpacing: 4,
              titleMarginBottom: 10,
              bodyFontFamily: "'Mukta'",
              bodyFontSize: 14,
              borderWidth: 2,
              borderColor: 'grey',
              callbacks:{
                title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    return data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index];
                },
                afterTitle: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                  var date = <?php echo json_encode($tempo) ?>

                  return date[tooltipItem[0]['index']]; 
                },
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                      var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';                  
                      if (label) {
                          label += ': ';
                      }
                      label += (tooltipItem.yLabel)+"A";                  
                      return label;
                }
              }
            },
            aspectRatio: 1,
            maintainAspectRatio: false
          }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save your data in a variable, loop through your data to get the right array entry and apply all your data you need to the chart and update it.

I can only give you this general solution without code as I don't want to analyze your code again after I already stated in an answer to another question of you that I don't think you have a good data structure.